# Php - passing variable inside an array

Tags: php, arrays

my script work fine if this function is written :

```
$extension_allowed =array(".pdf",".jpg",".jpeg",".png",".txt",".doc",".docx", ".odt", ".rtf", ".xls", ".xlsx", ".ods");
```

But, if I want config the extensions from application config and extract this extension from a query, how to pass the extensions inside an array?

```
// extensions
$extensionsUploadFileQ = mysql_query("
SELECT 
    *
FROM table_config
WHERE field1 = 'EXTENSIONS_UPLOAD'
");
$extensionsUploadFileR=mysql_fetch_array($extensionsUploadFileQ);
$extensionUploadFileParameter=$extensionsUploadFileR['value_extensions'];
```

the result of query, passing at the variable $extensionUploadFileParameter but not work by this array:

```
$extension_allowed =array($extensionUploadFileParameter);
```

How to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: `but not work` __HOW__?

Comment: If using array(".pdf",".jpg",".jpeg",".png",".txt",".doc",".docx", ".odt", ".rtf", ".xls", ".xlsx", ".ods"); the script responde with trust message.

But if using $extension_allowed =array($extensionUploadFileParameter); 
 the script responde with failure message.

Comment: What trust message are you talking about?

Comment: explore more your  problem

Comment: How you are storing this parameter? If it is stored as php code, you can eval this array (http://php.net/manual/pl/function.eval.php), or you can store it as a json (functions json_decode and json_encode)

Comment: go to exception message:        
 if(!in_array($ext,$extension_allowed)){           
           error_form("error upload"); //error

        }else{ 
......
}

Comment: `mysql_query` __*cringes*__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well in you MySQL DB you have your "EXTENSIONS_UPLOAD" as a string like ".pdf,.jpg,.jpeg,.png,.txt,.doc,.docx" and you want just to convert it to the PHP array type.

If yes then try to use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) PHP function:

```
// extensionUploadFileParameter = ".pdf,.jpg,.jpeg";
$extension_allowed = explode(",", $extensionUploadFileParameter);

/* 
   $extension_allowed will have:

   array(3)
   (
     [0] => string(4) ".pdf"
     [1] => string(4) ".jpg"
     [2] => string(4) ".jpeg"
   )
*/
```

OR

```
// extensionUploadFileParameter = '".pdf",".jpg",".jpeg"';
preg_match_all('/(.\w+)/', $extensionUploadFileParameter, $matches);  
$extension_allowed = $matches[0];

/*
 $extension_allowed will have:

 Array
 (
   [0] => .pdf
   [1] => .jpg
   [2] => .jpeg
 )
*/
```

I hope it helps.

Good luck.

P.S. Try to avoid using "[eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)" function:

> Caution The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it
>   allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged.
>   If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to
>   use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user
>   provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

Comment: in mySQL filed i have this value string: ".pdf",".jpg",".jpeg",".png",".txt",".doc",".docx", ".odt", ".rtf", ".xls", ".xlsx", ".ods"

I think: when this tring is extract from a query, was passing at the variable $extensionUploadFileParameter

Comment: **`array_explode()`** ?!

Comment: your first solution $extension_allowed = explode(",", $extensionUploadFileParameter); not work: response with an error message: File not uploaded.

Comment: your secon solution preg_match_all('/(.\w+)/', $extensionUploadFileParameter, $matches);  
$extension_allowed = $matches[0]; WORK FINE!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> in mySQL filed i have this value string: ".pdf",".jpg",".jpeg",".png",".txt",".doc",".docx", ".odt", ".rtf", ".xls", ".xlsx", ".ods" I think: when this tring is extract from a query, was passing at the variable $extensionUploadFileParameter – Frankie

You can use [eval](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.eval.php) function

```
eval('$extension_allowed = array(' . $extensionUploadFileParameter . ');');
```

Comment: I try your solution, but displayed this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in upload.php(452) : eval()'d code on line 1

Comment: I have fixed my solution. Pleas try this.

Comment: not work: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file ..  eval()'d code on line 1

Answer (score 0):

Thanks at all. The script work fine with this:

```
 preg_match_all('/(.\w+)/', $extensionUploadFileParameter, $matches);  
$extension_allowed = $matches[0];
```

eval() is dangerous:  The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code